# Connection between "IFA_CACHEINFO" rtnetlink attribute and "IFA_F_PERMANENT" flag in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, netlink

If I add a new IPv4 address to a network interface(for example, `ip -4 addr add 192.0.2.1/24 dev eth0`) without [rtnetlink](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) [IFA_CACHEINFO](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/if_addr.h#L60) attribute and then ask for IPv4 addresses configured on that interface(for example, `ip -4 addr show dev eth0`), then the rtnetlink result is returned with `IFA_F_PERMANENT` flag set. How and where in the kernel code are `IFA_CACHEINFO` attribute and `IFA_F_PERMANENT` flag connected?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3549.txt) the `IFA_F_PERMANENT` means that you specified the address yourself (you haven't let Linux come up with an address for you) and Linux will use it even after the interface is rebooted.

The `ip` command you used did exactly this, so that is why you got the `IFA_F_PERMANENT` flag and AFAIK it has nothing to do with `IFA_CACHEINFO`.

Answer (score 0):

The IFA_CACHEINFO attribute and IFA_F_PERMANENT flag are connected in the kernel code by the __rtnl_newlink() function. This function is responsible for allocating a new interface and setting up the IFA_CACHEINFO attributes with the IFA_F_PERMANENT flag set. The function is located in net/core/rtnetlink.c.